# How to create a loop with five (5) input variables?

Tags: bash, awk, variable-substitution

I have a proprietary command that requires five (5) inputs to properly execute the command.

```
command -cval <value> -tval <value> -dval <value> -kval <value>
```

I need to be able to have this command run by reading entries from a config file line by line so that when new requirements for these 5 values are given to me I can simply append a new row of data at the bottom of my config file and rerun the script.  Simple right???

My config file is set up with "GROUP" prefixed so I can grep only lines in the file containing "GROUP" this way so that new entries can be added to the config file easily in the same format to be processed (not sure this is a good idea):

```
## ORIG CONFIG FILE ##
cval, tval, dval, mval, kval    
cval, tval, dval, mval, kval
cval, tval, dval, mval, kval
...

## GROUP APPENDED CONFIG FILE ##
GROUP, cval, tval, dval, mval, kval     
GROUP, cval, tval, dval, mval, kval
GROUP, cval, tval, dval, mval, kval
...
```

PLEASE NOTE: These values in the config file can be duplicates that’s why I want them to be processed line by line.  Also I can set up the config file anyway I choose so please feel free to tell me why this way is or isn’t optimal.

My question:  How do I run the command in a loop to process my data like this:

LOOP1 (for first line)
command cval, tval, dval, mval, kval

LOOP2 (for second line)
command cval, tval, dval, mval, kval

LOOP3 (for third line)
command cval, tval, dval, mval, kval

... etc, etc, loop for each line in the config file.

Answer (score 6):

Given this file:

```
$ cat input
GROUP, cval1, tval1, dval1, mval1, kval1
DISREGARD, you, should, not, parse, this, line
GROUP, cval2, tval2, dval2, mval2, kval2
GROUP, cval3, tval3, dval3, mval3, kval3
```

And given this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, '/^GROUP/ {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input | while read c t d m k; do
  echo -cval $c -tval $t -dval $d -mval $m -kval $k
done
```

We get this result:

```
$ ./go.sh
-cval cval1 -tval tval1 -dval dval1 -mval mval1 -kval kval1
-cval cval2 -tval tval2 -dval dval2 -mval mval2 -kval kval2
-cval cval3 -tval tval3 -dval dval3 -mval mval3 -kval kval3
```

Replace `echo` with your proprietary command and you should be all set.

Comment: DopeGhoti you fricken' rock!  This works like a champ!  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 3):

With [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (and shamelessly borrowing the input provided in [DopeGhoti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448064/65304)

```
grep '^GROUP' input | parallel --col-sep ', *' -- \
  /bin/echo -cval {2} -tval {3} -dval {4} -mval {5} -kval {6}
```

Output:

```
-cval cval1 -tval tval1 -dval dval1 -mval mval1 -kval kval1
-cval cval2 -tval tval2 -dval dval2 -mval mval2 -kval kval2
-cval cval3 -tval tval3 -dval dval3 -mval mval3 -kval kval3
```

Replace `/bin/echo` by your actual command.

Comment: Small caveat: GNU Parallel will run one job per CPU core in parallel. So if your non-free command can not run in parallel (e.g. maybe it is using a fixed name file), then add `-j1` to run 1 jobs at a time.

Comment: @OleTange thanks, I suspected there might be a gotcha like that

Answer (score 2):

`sed` method:

```
sed -n '/^GR/{s/^GROUP/command/
              s/,/-c/
              s/,/-t/
              s/,/-d/
              s/,/-m/
              s/,/-k/
              s/-./ &val /gp}' input
```

Output (given what's in the *OP*):

```
command -cval cval -tval tval -dval dval -mval mval -kval kval
command -cval cval -tval tval -dval dval -mval mval -kval kval
command -cval cval -tval tval -dval dval -mval mval -kval kval
```

To actually run the output, (after carefully checking for any bad code in there), change the `gp` (*`g`lobal `p`rint*) at the end to a `ge` (*`g`lobal `e`valuate*).

Comment: Clever using the commas as placeholders for the switches in the command to be run.